# What am I doing wrong in this really basic UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview

I am trying to get this really basic UIScrollView to scroll horizontally and not vertically at all.  I am following this example here on the Xamarin developer site:  https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/create_a_horizontal_scrolling_button_list/  But I cannot get the buttons to take up the entire scroll view and only scroll horizontally.  I keep getting weird padding on the top and bottom of the list of buttons.  Here is my entire class:

```
public partial class StackViewController : UIViewController
{        
    public StackViewController()
    {            
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;            

        nfloat h = 50.0f;
        nfloat w = 50.0f;
        nint n = 25;
        UIScrollView scrollView = new UIScrollView
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(0, 100, View.Frame.Width, 100),
            ContentSize = new CGSize((w) * n, h),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {                
            var button = new UIButton();
            button.SetTitle(i.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);
            button.Frame = new CGRect((i * w), 0, w, h);
            button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;                
            scrollView.AddSubview(button);                
        }
        View.AddSubview(scrollView);
    }
}
```

[image: This code produces this image]

Somehow I am missing some padding or layout property that I don't know about.  I am semi-new to Xamarin ios development and I know that there is something simple that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollviews can often add indicator insets as well as content insets. What I'd suggest doing is to override the 'ViewDidLayoutSubviews' method and put in the following code:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
     base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

     scrollView.ContentInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
     scrollView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  Thank you.  I was looking for an attribute called 'padding' or something but came up with nothing.  This is it.